# PHP function to remove specified variables in a URL

Tags: php

I have created this function to remove specific variables from a string

```
if(!function_exists("remove_variable")) {
    function remove_variable($remove = array(), $url) {
        if($url == '') {
            $url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        }

        foreach($remove as $r) {
            echo $r.'<br>';
            $url = preg_replace('/([?&])'.$r.'=[^&]+(&|$)/','$1', $url);
            echo $url.'<br><br>';
        }

        return $url;
    }
}
```

I am testing with:

```
<?php echo remove_variable(array("productsearch_name", "productsearch_type", "productsearch_supplier"), $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].uri_glue()); ?>
```

Which is returning:

```
productsearch_name
/companies/customers/pricelist?productsearch_name=&productsearch_type=Broadband%20&productsearch_supplier=&

productsearch_type
/companies/customers/pricelist?productsearch_name=&productsearch_supplier=&

productsearch_supplier
/companies/customers/pricelist?productsearch_name=&productsearch_supplier=&

/companies/customers/pricelist?productsearch_name=&productsearch_supplier=&
```

So it is not removing the variables as expected

Comment: i would use `parse_str` not a regular expression

Comment: And then `array_diff_key()` with the array you want to remove.

Comment: @Dagon how would you use `parse_str ` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this way,

```
$str = "http://google.com/companies/customers/pricelist?productsearch_name=asd&productsearch_type=Broadband%20&productsearch_supplier=test";
parse_str(parse_url($str)['query'],$output);
print_r($output);
```

[parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) — Parses the string into variables.
[parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) — Parse a URL and return its components

I hope this will solve your problem.